# Importing multiple versions of the same Module/Package for Benchmarking

Tags: module, package, julia, benchmarking

I am working on a Package,
this package using BinDeps to pull in some C source code, and compile some binaries.

My julia module then mostly just exposes ccalls to those functions.

Now there are about 5 different options for how the C source can be compiled, with various different optimisations turned on.
And to go with them various other changes that are triggered by by a constant that is written to the `deps.jl` that is output by BinDeps.

So I would like to import each of the different builds of my package as different modules, so I can benchmark them using [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl).

Currently, my plan is to make a script that generates 5 different versions of my module, by copying it, and changing it's name, and by using a different `deps.jl` files to link to different compiled shared libraries.

And then (assuming I renamed them numerically):

```
using BenchmarkTools
import MyMod_1
import MyMod_2
import MyMod_3
import MyMod_4
import MyMod_5

@show @benchmark MyMod_1.foo() 
@show @benchmark MyMod_2.foo()
@show @benchmark MyMod_3.foo()
@show @benchmark MyMod_4.foo()
@show @benchmark MyMod_5.foo()
```

[Currently I am scripting the copying and renaming of modules.](https://github.com/oxinabox/SLEEF.jl/blob/d049850a3449d17e1508115e25908fd9ca6a0eae/bench/build_benchmarkable.jl)
It is a little scary, and seems a bit brittle.

But is there a better way?

Comment: Note that running multiple benchmarks within the same program isn't always a great idea.  The first one may run slower because it has to pay the startup overhead for some things that later runs also use.  (And then there's CPU clock speed ramp up from idle to max, and turbo max clock speed duration is limited depending on thermal effects, but that happens even with separate executables that you run from a shell script.)

Comment: Anyway, what I'd suggest is building multiple executables and running them with a shell script, if that's at all convenient for you, and there isn't a lot of time-consuming setup / warm-up work that has to happen before the stuff you want to measure.

Comment: Fair point, though I think BenchmarkTools.jl will work to minimise some of these issues. 
WRT building multiple executables (or in julias case, multiple scripts paired with multiple compiled shared libraries). That is what I am currently doing. See updated question.

Comment: I don't actually use or know Julia; I saw this question because of the [tag:benchmarking] tag.  Instead of actually moving libraries around, couldn't you just use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/build_4/ ./my_benchmark > build4.out`?  Or even `LD_PRELOAD=./mymod_5.so`?  (Assuming you're on GNU/Linux).  I would have done that with a shell script, since bash is great for stuff like this.  Oh, I guess you're doing something cross-platform, and you maybe don't have MinGW bash installed?  Anyway, I don't think I can help any further :/

Comment: @PeterCordes BenchmarkTools.jl alleviates this issue: It does some runs to compile and GC, and then it runs many times to find a mean, and stops when the mean is stable.

Comment: Writing a script to re-compile the library and re-run the test for each permutation seems much simpler and more robust... BenchmarkTools does take care to find a stable mean, but I doubt it knows anything about whether you are e.g. swapping out because of un-freed memory from previous runs.

Comment: (another issue with loading the shared library multiple times is symbol visibility and resolution order...)