# Importing multiple versions/branches of a module to benchmark in Julia

Tags: git, julia, benchmarking

How can I use several different versions or branches of the same module in a single script in Julia?

e.g. If I wanted to benchmark each of the tagged releases.

(Someone asked a similar question recently and I answered the wrong one but though this might be useful anyway.)

**Edit: I have answered this myself but I am sure their may be a better way!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just git checkout a different version of the module and then use benchmarkTools.jl to benchmark. However it may be better to use multiple scripts though (or at least ignore the first trial) (See this comment [Importing multiple versions of the same Module/Package for Benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219804/importing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-module-package-for-benchmarking/39224392?noredirect=1#comment65782781_39219804) for more info).

e.g.

```
packagedir = Pkg.dir("DSP")
version2checkout = "v0.0.7"
run(`cd $packagedir`); run(`git checkout tags/$version2checkout`)
import DSP
# do all your benmarking stuff
# start again
```

Prevents you from having to copy the modules but still a little clunky I guess.
You could even do it in a loop for lots of versions by capturing the output of git tag

```
for i in readlines(`git tag`)
    version2checkout = chomp(i)
    # checkout version and benchmark
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Note also that `Pkg.checkout` takes an optional `branch` argument:

```
help?> Pkg.checkout
  checkout(pkg, [branch="master"]; merge=true, pull=true)

  Checkout the Pkg.dir(pkg) repo to the branch branch. Defaults to checking
  out the "master" branch. To go back to using the newest compatible released
  version, use Pkg.free(pkg). Changes are merged (fast-forward only) if the
  keyword argument merge == true, and the latest version is pulled from the
  upstream repo if pull == true.
```

So you can do `Pkg.checkout("MyPackage", "v0.6.0")`. To ensure that modules are reloaded, the `workspace()` function might come in handy; or a new Julia process could be executed for each package version.

Comment: have you tried this? I couldn't get it to work. I thought you might need to use "tags/v0.6.0". Mind you I only tried on one package...

Comment: @AlexanderMorley I don't know why you need the `tags/`. It seems to work for me without.